# Reset permissions of app versus Google Play Game Services

Tags: permissions

When installing an app using Google Play Game Services (GPGS) on Android and booting the app first time, we give the app permission to do this and that with the user's account (or similar) on GPGS. How can I reset that permission, so that when the user accesses GPGS from the app the next time (using the same account as first time), it will ask for permission again?

Answer (score 0):

Within the GPGS service (leaderboard) inside the app itself, there was a button to access settings for the user vs the GPGS. I could disconnect the app from the account by digging around there. With that the permissions were revoked.